# Como ler corretamente uma API com JSON e criar lista?

Tags: python, json

Em Python3 eu fiz um programa para ler uma API (da Câmara dos Deputados) e pegar os dados em JSON

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://dadosabertos.camara.leg.br/api/v2/deputados'

# Primeiro eu fiz uma lista com dicionários - eles são os nomes dos deputados e o link da API respectiva de cada um. Os parâmetros foram json, número de itens por página e o número da página (são mais de 500 deputados, então são seis páginas
deputados = []
for pagina in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]:
    parametros = {'formato': 'json', 'itens': 100, 'pagina': pagina}
    resposta = requests.get(url, parametros)
    for deputado in resposta.json()['dados']:
        dicionario = {"deputado": deputado['nome'], "link_api": deputado['uri']}
        deputados.append(dicionario)

deputados
[{'deputado': 'ABEL MESQUITA JR.',
  'link_api': 'https://dadosabertos.camara.leg.br/api/v2/deputados/178957'},
 {'deputado': 'ADAIL CARNEIRO',
  'link_api': 'https://dadosabertos.camara.leg.br/api/v2/deputados/178864'},
 {'deputado': 'ADALBERTO CAVALCANTI',
  'link_api': 'https://dadosabertos.camara.leg.br/api/v2/deputados/178914'},
 {'deputado': 'ADELMO CARNEIRO LEÃO',
  'link_api': 'https://dadosabertos.camara.leg.br/api/v2/deputados/178890'},
 {'deputado': 'ADELSON BARRETO',
  'link_api': 'https://dadosabertos.camara.leg.br/api/v2/deputados/178968'},
 {'deputado': 'ADEMIR CAMILO',
  'link_api': 'https://dadosabertos.camara.leg.br/api/v2/deputados/133374'},
...


df = pd.DataFrame(deputados)
df.reset_index().head()
index   deputado    link_api
0   0   ABEL MESQUITA JR.   https://dadosabertos.camara.leg.br/api/v2/depu...
1   1   ADAIL CARNEIRO  https://dadosabertos.camara.leg.br/api/v2/depu...
2   2   ADALBERTO CAVALCANTI    https://dadosabertos.camara.leg.br/api/v2/depu...
3   3   ADELMO CARNEIRO LEÃO    https://dadosabertos.camara.leg.br/api/v2/depu...
4   4   ADELSON BARRETO     https://dadosabertos.camara.leg.br/api/v2/depu...


# Depois eu criei outra lista com dicionários. Desta vez eu quero ir em cada página de API de deputado e extrair alguns dos dados. Eu coloquei alguns prints para checar os resultados. O parâmetro agora é apenas json

perfis = []
for num, row in df.iterrows():
    parametros = {'formato': 'json'}
    resposta = requests.get(row['link_api'], parametros)
    print(resposta)
    for linha in resposta.json()['dados']:
        print(linha)
        item1 = linha['uri']
        item2 = linha['nomeCivil']
    for linha2 in resposta.json()['ultimoStatus']:
        item3 = linha2['nomeEleitoral']
        item4 = linha2['siglaPartido']
        item5 = linha2['siglaUf']
        item6 = linha2['urlFoto']
    for linha3 in resposta.json()['ultimoStatus/gabinete']:
        item7 = linha3['telefone']
        item8 = linha3['email']
        item9 = linha3['sexo']
        item10 = linha3['dataNascimento']
    dicionario = {"link_api": item1, "nome_completo": item2, "nome_eleitoral": item3, "partido": item4, "uf": item5, "link_foto": item6, "telefone": item7, "e_mail": item8, "sexo": item9, "data_nascimento": item2}    
    perfis.append(dicionario)
```

Aqui tive um erro (string indices must be integers) e os prints mostraram que a API do deputado não foi lida corretamente

```
<Response [200]>
id

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-bfada3632dc2> in <module>()
      6     for linha in resposta.json()['dados']:
      7         print(linha)
----> 8         item1 = linha['uri']
      9         item2 = linha['nomeCivil']
     10     for linha2 in resposta.json()['ultimoStatus']:

TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Depois testei individualmente um link de API e deu certo:

```
resposta = requests.get('https://dadosabertos.camara.leg.br/api/v2/deputados/178890')
print(resposta.json())
{'dados': {'id': 178890, 'uri': 'https://dadosabertos.camara.leg.br/api/v2/deputados/178890', 'nomeCivil': 'ADELMO CARNEIRO LEAO', 'ultimoStatus': {'id': 178890, 'uri': 'https://dadosabertos.camara.leg.br/api/v2/deputados/178890', 'nome': 'ADELMO CARNEIRO LEÃO', 'siglaPartido': 'PT', 'uriPartido': 'https://dadosabertos.camara.leg.br/api/v2/partidos/36844', 'siglaUf': 'MG', 'idLegislatura': 55, 'urlFoto': 'http://www.camara.leg.br/internet/deputado/bandep/178890.jpg', 'data': '2015-03-06', 'nomeEleitoral': 'ADELMO CARNEIRO LEÃO', 'gabinete': {'nome': '231', 'predio': '4', 'sala': '231', 'andar': '2', 'telefone': '3215-5231', 'email': 'dep.adelmocarneiroleao@camara.leg.br'}, 'situacao': 'Exercício', 'condicaoEleitoral': 'Suplente', 'descricaoStatus': None}, 'cpf': '', 'sexo': 'M', 'urlWebsite': None, 'redeSocial': [], 'dataNascimento': '1949-05-25', 'dataFalecimento': None, 'ufNascimento': 'MG', 'municipioNascimento': 'Itapagipe', 'escolaridade': 'Doutorado'}, 'links': [{'rel': 'self', 'href': 'https://dadosabertos.camara.leg.br/api/v2/deputados/178890'}]}
```

Por favor, isso pode significar que falta algum parâmetro quando tento criar a segunda lista?

Comment: Código está bem confuso para ler, então para facilitar, qual é o valor de `linha`? Pois parece que deveria ser um dicionário, pelo modo que está tentando acessar os valores, mas está vindo como *string*. Você não confundiu os objetos?

Comment: olá, obrigado. resposta aparece como: <Response [200]>. e linha como: id.

Comment: fiz o mesmo procedimento na primeira url (https://dadosabertos.camara.leg.br/api/v2/deputados) - crio um dicionário para cada informação e abasteço com o resposta json (aqui a linha se chama deputado)

mas quando repeti esse procedimento para as urls internas a resposta do json vem sem valor

Comment: O erro `TypeError: string indices must be integers`
é derivado da tentativa de acessar uma string como se fosse um dicionário.
Sua tentativa é semelhante a esta abaixo:
`>>> "palavra"['abc']`
```... TypeError: string indices must be integers```

Ou seja, linha é uma string e não um dicionário.